# identify element out of elements with similar class after a click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mouseover, buttonclick

I have a **jquery-ui dialog** box , which pops up when the user hovers the mouse pointer to certain few zoom images on a page .The dialogue box has few options for users to select after which he has to click a **confirm** button .There are multiple zoom images which have same class on the parent page .
How do I make a jquery function on the confirm button click to perform an action on the zoomed image or the zoomed-image's parent div/container , considering that the zoom images don't have their ids but a same class .

```
    $( ".cornerimage" ).mouseover(function() {
          $("#dialog").dialog( "open" );
        });


    $("#confirm").click(function(){

         });
```

Here is a  sample fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/uxk9kLa3/2/

Do i need to figure out which image was hovered and save it temporarily till the dialogue box is closed ...

[ps:the fiddle has external links for ui scripts n css]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Do i need to figure out which image was hovered and save it temporarily till the dialogue box is closed

**Yes**, one way or another. I'd recommend temporarily attaching a class to the originating image itself. Call `.addClass` when you open the dialog, and then call `.removeClass` when you've clicked on the confirm box:

```
$(".cornerimage").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("dialog-target");
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});


$("#confirm").click(function() {
  $(".dialog-target").removeClass("dialog-target");
  $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

Fiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/La7kaa9g/

You'd probably need some additional checks to make sure you don't end up with multiple `dialog-target`s, if the mouseover handler is triggered while a dialog is already open

Comment: thanks for the update `$("#confirm").click(function() {
  // do stuff with .dialog-target
  $(".dialog-target").parent().css("display","none")
  $(".dialog-target").removeClass("dialog-target");
});` , also i did somethign similar , Adding a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/La7kaa9g/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use this keyword, it will point to the current zoom image , eg

```
  $("#confirm").click(function(){
    $(this).(your code);
       });
```